# TypeScript React validation, array with fieldname as key

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to validate a form with react.
Having main Controller, which has the model and handles the actual validation.
Passing down model to child controllers, as well the validation errors.

How can i create an array which contains these errors, the array has a key which is  a field name in the model, and value is the validation error message. I want to bind the models field names to the error message. Class for example what im 
 looking for.

```
export class Model {
   SampleNumber: number;
   SampleString: string;
   Errors: [keyof Model, string];
}
```

Or is there a preferred way of handling validation messages in React with typescript.

Comment: Arrays don't have keys - you need to use an object for `Errors` if you want it to be contain key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, arrays don't have keys - you need to use an object for Errors if you want it to be contain key-value pairs.

If you want to specify the type of an object's keys, you'd use an index signature, like so:

```
export class Model {
    SampleNumber: number;
    SampleString: string;
    Errors: { [x: string]: string };
}
```

However, you can't currently use `keyof Model` alone in an index signature - you need to use a ['mapped type'](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types) instead, by specifying `field in keyof Model`. You can then combine this with the `Partial` mapped type to make it so not every field has to be present.

```
export class Model {
    SampleNumber: number;
    SampleString: string;
    Errors: Partial<{ [field in keyof Model]: string }>;
}

let model: Model = {
    SampleNumber: 1,
    SampleString: "",
    Errors: { SampleNumber: "error" }
};
```